# How to handle multiple args of callback function in async/await format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async-await, try-catch

In shelljs, the exec function has 3 arguments in callback `(err, stdout, stderr)`. When using this in `async/await` by `promisify(shelljs.exec)`, I'm not able to catch the `stderr`?

```
const { promisify } = require('util'),
  shellExec = promisify(shelljs.exec);

....

// in the function

try {
 variableName = await shellExec('some valid shell command', {});

 return variableName;
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

If shelljs exec return code 0 i.e. valid response it works fine, but when the the command is invalid, it returns 1.

I'm not able to get the `stderr`.

Comment: The return value from the awaited promise should have an object with the `stderr`. Take a read at this http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html point 3

Comment: The is exactly what i wanted to know, but it doesn't solves my issue. The issue is with shelljs, in case of error from shell, if goes to catch block instead of then.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want the value of stderr to output while also using async/await. Something like this might be of use:

```
var shelljs = require('shelljs');

async function promiseExec(input) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let { err, stdout, stderr } = shelljs.exec(input);
    shelljs.exit(1);
    if(stdout === "") reject(stderr);
    resolve(stdout);
  })
}

async function main () {
  let result = await promiseExec('dir');
  console.log(result);
}

main();
```

Comment: This code works but then i'm unable to differentiate between `stderr` and `stdout`

Comment: You can return an object from the promise and destructure the keys for example.
What you are asking can be done in a simple way since you have stdout and stderr seperated within the promise definition,